# How to select last modified dateTime for each ItemModel

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by, left-join

I already select data from 2 tables which is

```
SELECT  H.CostControlID, H.ItemModel, H.effDate,H.LstMdf, D.DTP
FROM PBMHCostControl H
LEFT JOIN PBMDCostControl D
ON H.CostControlID = D.CostControlID
```

This is the highlighted result of above queries

| ItemModel | LastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- |
| NC-500 | 2010-09-04 03:23:43.000 |
| NC-500 | 2010-05-04 10:57:40.000 |
| NC-500 | 2010-05-04 10:57:56.000 |
| NC-600 | 2010-05-04 10:57:57.000 |
| NC-600 | 2010-05-04 11:57:57.000 |

But I want the result to be like this

| ItemModel | LastModifiedDate |
| --- | --- |
| NC-500 | 2010-05-04 10:57:56.000 |
| NC-600 | 2010-05-04 11:57:57.000 |

Comment: Which database system are you using ?

Comment: You select 4 columns, but the expected result only has 2 columns. What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `group by` and the aggregate function `max()` :

```
SELECT  H.ItemModel, MAX(H.LstMdf) as LastModifiedDate
FROM PBMHCostControl H
LEFT JOIN PBMDCostControl D ON H.CostControlID = D.CostControlID
GROUP BY H.ItemModel
```